# Short story ID: colonists on alien planet have problem of deadly bouncing creatures

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

A short story, probably from sometime between 1960s through 1990s, that I read either in an anthology or in a magazine like Analog or Asimov's, about a guy who describes how he has to figure out how to solve the problem afflicting the human colony on an alien planet he's on.

The issue is that there are native creatures that are kind of like extremely light, bouncy tumbleweeds, and they seem to be just barely intelligent enough to be curious about people, so if you open your front door in the morning you can get impacted by a bunch of them that have been waiting around, eager to bounce into you.

Unfortunately, something like one in twenty of the bouncer creatures is immediately fatal for humans to contact (which ones, it's visually impossible to tell), through some biochemical quirk (though if I recall correctly, there is no evidence the creatures are intentional in their lethality). This makes any walking outside a gamble with one's life, unless wearing heavy protective gear, putting the viability of the colonization in peril. High walls or moats don't work — the creatures manage to drift or bounce over any walls erected around the colony, no matter how high.

I think the narrator had a bitter tone (but amusing, in a cynical way)  as he complained about his frustration with the stupid situation, and mentioned what he'd like to do (should they ever meet) to the grossly negligent scout who failed to note the deadly problem and instead reported the planet safe for colonization.

I don't recall what the answer to the problem was, but I think the main character did work out some surprisingly simple solution in the end.

Comment: I would like to read this, hope you get an answer.

Comment: This almost reminds me of ptertha and pterthacosis from *The Wooden Spaceships* by Bob Shaw.

Comment: I wonder if that's the planet where the Dark Star crew picked up their pet.  https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/Beach_Ball_Alien

Comment: Did they demand *bouncing, then rolling, then bouncing of the third kind*?

Comment: Sounds a tiny bit like [When the People Fell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_People_Fell).

Comment: @Simon Thanks, I see what you mean about similarity, but I'm pretty sure that's not it.